# SQL Remove Extended ASCII Characters But Leave Foreign Characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, character-encoding

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

I have a dilemma where I often received data with foreign (Chinese) characters that is co-mingled with non-printable characters.  This data is from forensic applications that typically carve remnants of metadata from unallocated space, so the results can include a lot of junk.

I'd like a TSQL statement or function to remove these non-printable characters, but leave the foreign characters as it's important to preserve actual filenames, paths, etc.

I've used functions that I've found online - this site mostly, but they remove everything.  As an example, take this string:

```
http://abcde/Work/員工離序¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬®**及注意事項_files/pic001.gif
```

I'd like to remove the junk in the middle of the string, and return this:

```
http://abcde/Work/員工離序及注意事項_files/pic001.gif
```

Comment: yes (`SQL Server 2014 Enterprise`)

Comment: Willing to use [SQL CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) to get the power of .NET regex? [Tutorial](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) (Also, check for open source to evaluate and drop in.) If so, you'd not only get regex replace but also be able to filter by named [Unicode categories and blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#CategoryOrBlock).

Comment: Note: It's very unclear what you mean by "Extended ASCII Characters"; Is it the union of the characters in all so-called extended ASCII character sets minus the characters in the ASCII character set?; maybe just drop it because surely you are using NVARCHAR (Unicode UTF-16). And, what you mean by "non-printable", currency symbols are certainly printable.

Comment: In addition to @TomBlodget I'd suggest to create a black list of unwanted characters and kick them specifically...